# Prove that $TQ$ is parallel to $PW$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

The problem is the one below

[image]

it has two parts: first one is to show that $M$ is the midpoint of $PR$ which is pretty trivial and can be assumed as a known result (the proof consists of drawing a parallel to $PR$ through $Q$ and play with trivial polar theorems).

The second part is the one I'm struggling with: It states that $PW \parallel TQ$ which is clearly not an homothetic fact and the angles are hard to find. I do think it is related to the symedian of the contact triangle in the ex-incircle, but I couldn't work it.

Comment: Isn't möbius inversion about number theory? Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @youthdoo you're right. I confused möebius inversion with möebius transformation. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming standard notations, you have $\dfrac{MP}{PT} = \dfrac{a}{2(s-a)} = \dfrac{a}{b+c-a},$ so you just need to show $\dfrac{MW}{WQ}$ is equal to this ratio. For that, draw the altitude from $Q$ and call its foot $H$ and let the point of tangency of the incircle to side $PR$ be $S$, then you have:
$$\dfrac{MW}{WQ} = \dfrac{MS}{SH} = \dfrac{MP-PS}{PS-PH} = \dfrac{a/2 - s+b}{s-b-c\cos\beta} = \dfrac{\dfrac{b-c}{2}}{\dfrac{a+c-b}{2}-\dfrac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2a}} = \dfrac{a(b-c)}{a(c-b)-c^2+b^2} = \dfrac{a}{b+c-a}.$$

Here, the notation with non-conventional letters were annoying me so I used the sidelengths and corresponding angles are $a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ respectively for $P,R,Q$ and $s$ is of course the semiperimeter. In the case of $b=c,$ your problem will be degenerately trivial.